# change eol character via cmd

Tags: cmd, eol

i have a file `file1`in with unix eol, 
i have a script to do some editing in it, but the editing is done into `output.txt` and is renamed as `file1`and this changes the eol to windows/dos

the code is given

```
set uu=file1
set vv=file2

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (%uu%) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   if "!line:345=!" neq "!line!" (
      if "!line:123=!" neq "!line!" (
         if not defined flag (
            findstr "123" %vv% | findstr "345"
            set flag=true
         )
      ) else (
         echo !line!
      )
   ) else (
      echo !line!
   )
)) >output.txt 
del %uu% 
rename output.txt file1
```

any way to change it back or retain unix eol via cmd without user input?

have tried directly inputing into the file1, gives a 0 kb file
tried `type output.txt>file1` gave dos/win eol
echoing anything other than a blank line `echo.>file1` changed the eol char

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: What eol do you mean with "unix" (eg CR only, CRLFCR)?

Comment: using batch scripts.  @endoro, dont really know, till now i just used notepad++ and changed EOL coversion to unix/osx format from windows/dos.

Comment: tried wiki and it said LF

Comment: this is windows eol `
`

Comment: this is linux eol `
`

Comment: so i have to find all of 1 and replace it with the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
@echo off
::Syntax: batchfile "file.txt" >"file2.txt"

:init
for /f %%c in ('copy /z "%~dpnx0" nul') do set cr=%%c
(set lf=^

)
del file.tmp 2>nul
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" "%~1"') do (
set "line=%%i"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "line=!line:*:=!!lf!"
echo(!line!
endlocal
)>>file.tmp
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
findstr /v "!cr!!lf!" file.tmp
endlocal
del file.tmp 2>nul
```

Comment: aaand it cant run coz i have 64 bit :(

Comment: I edited the post above.  My original text was as follows:  Horst Schaeffer wrote `CRLF.COM` which has some smarts, if you have a `32 bit windows`. http://www.horstmuc.de/horst.htm

Comment: can you explain a bit more its working?  btw in view, i clicked show symbols, and the lf variable is set as CRLF not LF

Comment: yes, i dont know where to replace the filenames either?  sorry if i come out as noob

Comment: If you call the batch file dos2unix.bat then the command will be `dos2unix "filein.txt" >"fileout.txt"`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "uu=file1"
set "vv=file2"
set LF=^


rem keep two empty lines between set LF and here
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (%uu%) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   if "!line:345=!" neq "!line!" (
      if "!line:123=!" neq "!line!" (
         if not defined flag (
            findstr "123" %vv% | findstr "345"
            set flag=true
         )
      ) else (
         <nul set/p"=!line!!LF!"
      )
   ) else (
      <nul set/p"=!line!!LF!"
   )
)) >output.txt 
type output.txt
```

Comment: nope, still dos format. when i click on show eol char, it shows set lf=^ CRLF not LF. even tried making it LF by using unix format still doenst work

Comment: No all lines get **only** `LF` on the end, look inside with a hex editor. Please note the two empty lines, if they aren't empty this **doesn't work**.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure `CMD` I'd say unlikely.

`GNU SED` should be capable of this transformation though.

```
sed -b s/\r//g infile >outfile
```

Comment: gnu sed is not portable, is it?  if not any portable solutions?

Comment: copied the same line, but the eol is not changed

Comment: GnuSED can't do it.  VBS should be able to open a file and write the lines with a LF and otherwise no line ending.

Comment: Hmm - revised command worked for me. What do you mean by "portable"? It's a freely-available utility. `GNU SED` is the DOS flavour. Ux has its own version. What platforms are you targeting that are likely to run CMD on which `GNU SED` can' run?